# Error : Running array of objects in JavaFX with same method

Tags: javafx

Here's the code :

**Main File :**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package testobjectarray;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * 
 */



public class TestObjectArray extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application. main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs
     * with limited FX support. NetBeans ignores main().
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

        myClass[] c = new myClass[5];
        c[2].myMethod();
    }

}
```

**Class declared outside :**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package testobjectarray;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class myClass {
    public void myMethod(){
        System.out.println("Inside myMethod");
    }
}
```

Problem, I get errors when I compile i.e. initializing an array of objects and invoking the method. If I have just one object, it works great. Any help appreciated.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by making an array of `myClass` just after `launch(args)` ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha, I need to calculate distances for a collection of points. I just put a template here. And because I want to use it in JavaFX.

Comment: Trying to put it somewhere else, as the code below launch will never be called unless you close the stage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are initialising an array of size 5, but you never add values to it. Try the following code

```
myClass[] c = new myClass[5];
c[0] = new myClass();
c[1] = new myClass(); // and so on till c[4]
//now you can call the methods
c[1].myMethod();
```